# Perl - anonymous hashmaps and arrays - few questions

Tags: arrays, perl, perl-data-structures

Hello I am learning perl and I will post several assumptions here. So please feel free to commenting and correcting me if I am wrong somewhere.

1. Creating hash are done (among several another ways) by:

   ```
   %numbers = qw(one 1 two 2);
   ```
2. Creating array are done by following:

   ```
   @array = qw(one two);
   ```
3. Above constructions represents "non anonymous" types. The main difference between non anonymous and anonymous types is that named types have a name which I can refer to. If I want to create anonymous types I need to change parenthesis `()` for square brackets `[]` in arrays, or for braces `{}` in hashes. Hash of hashes in other words are hash of references to other hashes. Thus I need to use `{}` in nested hash and not classic hash `()`.

   ```
   %HoH = (
       flintstones => {
           husband   => "fred",
           pal       => "barney",
       },
       jetsons => {
           husband   => "george",
           wife      => "jane",
           "his boy" => "elroy",  # quotes needed on key.
       },
       simpsons => {
           husband   => "homer",
           wife      => "marge",
           kid       => "bart",
       },
   );
   ```
4. The same situation applies for multi dimensional arrays. Multi dimensional array is an array containing refernces to another array, thus [] needs to be used instead ().

   ```
   @array_of_arrays =  ( [ "one", "two", "three" ],
                         [  4,   5,  6,  7  ],
                         [ "alpha", "beta" ]
                       );
   ```
5. If I had "non anonymous" hashes containing each family members (flinstones, jetsons, simpsons) which construction should I use for creating `%HOH`?

   ```
   $HOH{flinstones} = {%flinstones};
   ```

   or

   ```
   $HOH{flinstones} = \%flinstones;
   ```

   I am assuming that `\%flinstones` is simply assigning reference to `$HOH{flinstones}`, this means that whatever I do to `%flinstones` will influence the `$HOH{flinstones}` because it simply contains reference to it. On the other hand `{%flinstones}` is something like re-casting of "non anonymous" hash to "anonymous" hash. This has effect that `%flinstones` can be later modified or even deleted and it will not affect the `$HOH{flinstones}` because there is reference to anonymous hash.
6. What will happen with variable in loop? When `my $variable;` is issued inside loop it overwrites old one or creates new, or it is the same variable, or what happens here?

   ```
   for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){
     my $variable=$i;
     print $variable
   }
   ```

Comment: You should only ask one question per question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I call them "literal hash", "literal array", but to each his own.

You should know that in Perl--except in case of [`tie`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltie.html)s-- `[...]` and `\@x` are pretty much the same thing. And that `{...}` and `\%h` are as well. They both "construct" references to arrays and hashes.

In question 5, both will do what you want. *But* one will do it more efficiently. Your second example stores the reference to an already defined hash as a value in another hash. The first example,

```
$HOH{flinstones} = {%flinstones}
```

creates a hash to return the address and *expands* `%flintstones` into a list, per the list context. Thus it stores a hash that is an exact copy of `%flintstones` in a separate hash that is stored in `%HOH`. You are correct that changes to `%flintstones` will not affect this copy.

Here's a bit of advice for you. Install, [`Smart::Comments`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Smart%3a%3aComments) (SC), create some test scripts and just dump variable internals through STDERR. You'll be amazed at how much more you can learn seeing the internals of everything, you care to see.

Here are some lessons from my experience with SC:

- set `$Data::Dumper::Maxdepth` to some positive integer value if you're going to dump `Win32::OLE` objects, as each reference of the same OLE object may look like a different Perl object when traversed.
- Never dump `$_` by itself. For some reason the code in SC can change it. So always do something like this:

  ```
  my $a = $_;
  ### $_ : $a
  ```
- IO handles don't dump, so don't try it. Use the default stringification.

Now, finally, if you didn't dump `%flintstones` with `%HOH`, you would have no way of knowing--through a simple variable dump--whether the references were the same or not. However, remember that you can set `$Data::Dumper::Maxdepth` so that you won't get a complete dump. So you can test whether or not two references were the same by partially dumping them and using the straight generic Perl stringification of references.

```
### %flintstones : '' . \%flintstones 
local $Data::Dumper::Maxdepth = 1;
### %HOH
```

Seeing for yourself what the case is, is going to help you learn Perl faster than asking a raft of questions on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

As for question 5, which I assume is question 1, you can use both. Although you should realize that the first method:

```
$HOH{flinstones} = {%flinstones}
```

Is simply making a shallow copy of the `%flinstones` hash, where it is expanded into a list of its keys and values. Whereas

```
$HOH{flinstones} = \%flinstones
```

Is passing the hash as a reference, so that both hashes point to the same location in memory.

As for question 6, what happens with a lexically scoped variable? Lets take a look at `perldoc -f my`:

```
A "my" declares the listed variables to be local (lexically) to
the enclosing block, file, or "eval".
```

A for-loop is a block, which means that any variable declared with `my` inside the for-loop is local to that loop, and local to each iteration of that loop. Which means that if you do something like this:

```
for my $number (0 .. 3) {
    print "Number is $_. Last number was $last\n";
    my $last = $_;                       # WRONG!
}   # $last goes out of scope here!
```

It will give you lots of `Use of uninitialized value` warnings. You need to extend the scope:

```
my $last = "N/A";  # default value
for my $number (0 .. 3) {
    print "Number is $_. Last number was $last\n";
    $last = $_;
}
```

Now, I don't know if this was intentional on your part, but you can combine both of these questions into one:

```
my %HOH;
{ # begin a block to reduce scope of variables
    my %flinstones = (
        husband   => "fred",
        pal       => "barney",
    );
    $HOH{flinstones} = \%flinstones;
} 
... # %flinstones hash is now out of scope, stored only in %HOH
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`{ LIST }`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References) construction takes a list of values, builds an anonymous hash out of them (just as if you assigned the same list to a named hash with `%hash = (LIST)`) and returns a reference to that hash.

There's nothing special about "anonymous hashes" in Perl: they're ordinary hashes like any others.  The only thing that makes them "anonymous" is that they don't (currently) have a name, so you can only refer to them using a reference.

Being bound to a variable name isn't an intrinsic property of hashes, either: it's quite possible for a named hash to become anonymous (e.g. if the name it had goes out of scope) or even for an anonymous hash to acquire a name through [symbol table manipulation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles), like this:

```
my $hashref = {foo => 'bar'};
our %hash;             # required by "use strict"
*hash = $hashref;
print "$hash{foo}\n";  # prints "bar"
```

After the line `*hash = $hashref`, the global variable `%hash` becomes a new name for the hash pointed to by the reference `$hashref`, regardless of whether it already had a name before or not.  This mechanism even allows the same hash to have more than one name: in fact, any Perl module that lets you export a hash (or any other kind of variable) from its own namespace into yours essentially does just this under the hood.

Of course, all of the above also applies to arrays (and, indeed, to scalars too) just as well.

---

As for your last question, [`my`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Private-Variables-via-my%28%29) in fact does create a new lexically scoped variable every time it's executed, rather than reusing the same variable each time.  This doesn't actually make any difference for your example code, but one situation where it *would* make a difference is if you saved a reference to the variable before it went out of scope.  For example, the following is a fairly common way to parse tab-separated data into an array:

```
my @table;
while (my $line = <>) {
    chomp $line;
    my @row = split /\t/, $line;
    # maybe do some manipulation or checks on @row here...
    push @table, \@row;
}
```

If you test this, you'll find that this code indeed fills `@table` with references to a different (now anonymous) array for each row, rather than with many references pointing to the same array.